# zip argument #2 must support iterationzip argument #2 must support iteration column transformer error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i am using the column transformer for the first time and I keep getting a Type Error, is something wrong with the code?

code :

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer(('cat',OrdinalEncoder(),['job_industry_category','job_title','wealth_segmenr','gender']),
                               ('numb',MinMaxScaler(),['tenure', 'age'])

data_impute = transformer.fit_transform(data_impute)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-ca10f9ee762b> in <module>
----> 1 data_impute = transformer.fit_transform(data_impute)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    512             self._feature_names_in = None
    513         X = _check_X(X)
--> 514         self._validate_transformers()
    515         self._validate_column_callables(X)
    516         self._validate_remainder(X)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_transformers(self)
    271             return
    272 
--> 273         names, transformers, _ = zip(*self.transformers)
    274 
    275         # validate names

TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Comment: `*self.transformers` is like passing all elements of `self.transformers` to `zip`. Check what is the type of the second element of `self.transformers` I bet it's not an iterable/list/whatever

Comment: What is in `data_impute` before these two lines of code are run?  @Jean-FrançoisFabre - where you're talking about is not his code.  It's two levels down in the `sklearn` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrong construction of the `ColumnTransformer` object results in passing wrong arguments to the internal `zip` call, resulting in a useless error message for the mere mortal.

constructor is

> class sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer(transformers, *, remainder='drop', sparse_threshold=0.3, n_jobs=None, transformer_weights=None, verbose=False)[source]¶

The wrong construction code passes `transformers` as `('cat',OrdinalEncoder(),'job_industry_category','job_title','wealth_segmenr','gender'])` then `remainder` as `('numb',MinMaxScaler(),['tenure', 'age'])`, then it fails miserably...

from an example in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(
     [("norm1", Normalizer(norm='l1'), [0, 1]),
      ("norm2", Normalizer(norm='l1'), slice(2, 4))])
```

you must pass a *list* of tuples, not the tuples as arguments

fix:

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer([   # note the [ to start the list
 ('cat',OrdinalEncoder(),'job_industry_category','job_title','wealth_segmenr','gender']),
 ('numb',MinMaxScaler(),['tenure', 'age'])
])  # note the ] to end the list
```

The datascience modules generally lack strong type hinting or type checking. Read the docs + copy/adapt the examples instead of starting from a blank page!

Comment: Got it to work like this  : `t = [('cat', OrdinalEncoder(),['job_industry_category','job_title','wealth_segment','gender']),
                                ('numb',MinMaxScaler(),['tenure', 'age'])]
transformer = ct(transformers=t) `